# Having a hidden id for <options> in thymleaf and Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I have a thymleaf bootstrap front end that i want to be able to update and add new employee , but employee has a relation with department and has only id of department but i need to show the names of department through options, i am trying to translate that into thymleaf code

```
<div class="card-body">
                        <form>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-control-label"
                                       for="field_department">Department</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="field_department">

                                    <option value="0">CEO</option>
                                    <option value="1">Accounting</option>
                                    <option value="2">Java</option>
                                    <option value="3">Testing</option>
                                    <option value="4">People management</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label class="form-control-label"
                                       for="field_employeeName">Employee Name</label>
                                <input class="form-control"
                                       id="field_employeeName"
                                       type="text"
                                       value="Ivan Ivanov"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

When i choose department how can i connect each option to the id of departments from the back end.

Comment: Are you using **thymeleaf** with **Spring MVC** ?

Comment: yes i am using spring mvc

Comment: As my understanding you need to link the department with Employee when create the an employee . And you need to show the list of departments one creation of employee so the user can select one department . Correct ?

Comment: yes thats right

Answer (score 0):

First you should define the relationship between Employee and Department models. Below is example in JPA .

Department Model

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Department Table 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department {

    /**
     * 
     *  Department Number
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "number")
    private int number ;


    /**
     * 
     *  Department name
     */
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name ;


    /**
     * 
     *  Department employees
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private Set<Employee> employees ;

    public Department() {
        if(employees == null) {
            employees = new HashSet<>() ;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Number Getter
     * @return Department Number 
     */
    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    /**
     * Number Setter
     * @param number Department Number
     * 
     */
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    /**
     * Name Getter
     * @return Department Name 
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Name Setter
     * @param name Department name
     * 
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Department To String 
     * @return Department in String
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Department [number=" + number + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }



}
```

Employee Model

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {


   /**
     * Employee ID
     */
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

   /**
     * Employee name
     * 
     */
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name ;


   /**
     * Employee job position
     * 
     */
    @Column(name = "Job") 
    private String job ;


   /**
     * Salary of employee
     * 
     */
    @Column(name = "Salary")
    private float salary ;

    /**
     * Employee Gender
     */
    private char gender;

   /**
     * Employee department
     * 
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Dno")
    private Department department;


    public Employee() {

    }


   /**
     * <code>id</code> getter
     * @return Employer id
     * 
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * <code>id</code> setter
     * @param id Employee id 
     * 
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

   /**
     * <code>name</code> getter
     * @return Employer name
     * 
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

   /**
     * <code>name</code> setter
     * @param name Employee name 
     * 
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


   /**
     * <code>job</code> getter
     * @return Staff position
     * 
     */
    public String getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    /**
     * <code>job</code> setter
     * @param job Employee job 
     * 
     */
    public void setJob(String job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    /**
     * <code>salary</code> getter
     * @return Employer salary
     * 
     */
    public float getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    /**
     * <code>salary</code> setter
     * @param salary Employee salary 
     * 
     */
    public void setSalary(float salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }



    public char getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(char gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    /**
     *
     * Employee Department Getter
     * @return Return Employee Department
     */
    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    /**
     * Employee Department Setter
     * @param {@link Department} <a>Employee department></a>
     */
    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }



    /**
     * Convert an employee to string 
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", job=" + job + ", salary=" + salary + ", gender=" + gender
                + "Department = "+department.getNumber()  + "]";
    }


}
```

In the controller that you used to add the Employee , first you should pass the list of available departments to view from databases with initialized object of employee class .Below example to do it when the user request Add employee page.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String add(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("employee",new Employee());
    model.addAttribute("departments",departmentService.getList());
    return "add";
}
```

The method `getList()` is uses to get the list of departments use Department Repository

```
@Service("departmentService")
public class DepartmentService {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentRepository departmentRepository ;


    public List<Department> getList() {
        return departmentRepository.findAll();
    }

    public DepartmentRepository getDepartmentRepository() {
        return departmentRepository;
    }

    public void setDepartmentRepository(DepartmentRepository departmentRepository) {
        this.departmentRepository = departmentRepository;
    }


}
```

The thymeleaf form of add new employee will be as below .

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/employee/add}" th:object="${employee}" method="post">
     <table>
       <tr th:if="${#fields.hasAnyErrors()}">
         <td th:each="error : ${#fields.allErrors()}" th:text="${error}"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td>

             <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" class ="inputeText" th:errorclass="errorIncput">
             <span  th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}"></span>
         </td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Job</td>
         <td>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{job}">
            <span  th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('job')}" th:errors="*{job}"></span>
         </td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Gender</td>
         <td>
           <ul>
             <li><input type="radio" th:field="*{gender}" value="M"/> Male</li>
              <li><input type="radio" th:field="*{gender}" value="F"/> female</li>
           </ul>

         </td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Salary</td>
         <td><input type="number" th:field="*{salary}"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Department</td>
         <td>
           <select th:field="*{department.number}">
              <option 
                    th:each="department : ${departments}"
                    th:text="${department.name}"
                    th:value="${department.number}" />
           </select>
           <span  th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('department.number')}" th:errors="*{department.number}" ></span>
           <span  th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('department')}" th:errors="*{department}" ></span>
         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td colspan="2">
          <input type="submit" value="Add"/></td>
       </tr>
     </table>
  </form>
```

One user click add to submit the form you will have `RequestMapping` in EmployeeController to process this action .

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addSave(
             @ModelAttribute("employee")Employee employee , 
             BindingResult bindingResult , Model model) {

             }
```

The `employee` object received from view will have already linked with department selected by user .